# How to signal errors / failures in iOS App Intents?

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts

the new AppIntents allow a simple code-driven implementation for Siri Shortcuts.
In the `perform()` function we need to return `some IntentResult` or throw an error if something went wrong.

My question now is: How do I throw an error that can then be inspected by the user?
Let's say the user wants to interact with a CoreData object that he has deleted earlier. Now he/she runs the shortcut and it must fail, because the object is not available.
I tried to implement a custom `LocalizedError`, but in the *Shortcuts* app I only get an error message telling me something about an unknown error. The description text is not shown in *Shortcuts*.

Feedback ID: FB11434135

Kind regards 
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on this, but during the migration of my intents I ended up using a property `localizedStringResource` like this:

```
struct MyIntent: AppIntent {
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Start My Intent"

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {

        if !doSomething() {
            throw MyIntentError.message("Hello, I'm an error!")
        }
        
        return .result(dialog: IntentDialog("My answer"))
    }
    
    func doSomething() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

enum MyIntentError: Swift.Error, CustomLocalizedStringResourceConvertible {
    case general
    case message(_ message: String)

    var localizedStringResource: LocalizedStringResource {
        switch self {
        case let .message(message): return "Error: \(message)"
        case .general: return "My general error"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple mentioned that this is only documented in a WWDC video